# KinematicBody2D moves only to left and right

Tags: 2d, godot

So i'm a complete newbie to coding and so i followed this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeSJgUTLmk0

And the i cant move KinematicBody2D up nor down

Here's the code

```
extends KinematicBody2D


var MaxSpeed = 500 
var Accel = 5000
var Motion = Vector2.ZERO


func _physics_process(delta):
    var Axis = GetInputAxis()
    if Axis == Vector2.ZERO:
        ApplyFriction(Accel * delta)
    else:
        ApplyMovement(Axis * Accel * delta)
    Motion = move_and_slide(Motion)

func GetInputAxis():
    var Axis = Vector2.ZERO
    Axis.x = Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    Axis.y - Input.get_action_strength("ui_up") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_down")
    return Axis.normalized()

func ApplyFriction(amount):
    if Motion.length() > amount:
        Motion -= Motion.normalized() * amount
    else:
        Motion = Vector2.ZERO

func ApplyMovement(acceleration):
    Motion += acceleration
    Motion = Motion.clamped(MaxSpeed)
```

and yes my keybinds are set properly

Comment: In your second last line, you have `Motion += acceleration`. Is this correct, or did you mean `Motion += Accel`?

Comment: i dont know why that is but the problem is that i put - instead of = after Axis.y